# Solve linear system with Cramer's formula

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, systems-of-equations

How to solve this system of two equations with three unknowns with Cramer's formula:
$$\begin{cases} x-y+3z&=&0\\
  2x-2y+6z&=&0
\end{cases}$$
I tried to find $\Delta xy$, $\Delta xz$, $\Delta yz$ and all of them are equal to $0$, so I think the system doesn't have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Both equations are multiple of each other. Hence, all $(x,y,z)$ with $x=y-3z$ are valid solutions.

You could write down all solutions like 
$$v = (y-3z,y,z)^T=y(1,1,0)^T+z(-3,0,1)^T$$
where $y,z \in R$ are arbitrary constants.